# 404.3 Error for .php extensions on IIS 10

Tags: php, iis

I've used WEBPI to install PHP 7.1 on IIS 10 in an attempt to develop PHP on a local machine. I get this error when navigating to a .php file:

HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

- CGI is activated
- ASP.NET is installed
- The handler is mapped in FASTCGI (C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.1\php-cgi.exe) in the IIS Manager
- HTTP Activation is ON
- aspnet_regiis.exe -ir has been run

Why aren't PHP file extensions being recognized?

Comment: Run PHP Diagnostics, and it should give you some hints, https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/php-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your handler mappings? It should contain a mapper of FastCGI to php files. Fixed the error in my case.